# Unity Recorder by scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recorder

I have several cameras on my stage, each camera films a character who makes a single animation.

I want to record in a `.mp4` file, for each camera, the animation of my character and that just with a script that I put in an Empty object.
Let's imagine, I launch with the player button, for each camera, Unity launches a Recorder of twenty seconds, records in a `.mp4` file, then activates another camera, relaunch the scene with a Recorder of 20 secs etc etc.

How to drive the Unity Recorder by script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen recorder package has code samples to drive it by a script.
Package Manager > Recorder, at the right pane you will see Samples at the bottom. "MovieRecorderExample" contains an example to record .mp4.